# setOnItemClickListener is not working in app chooser

Tags: android, xml, android-intent

I'm making a pdf viewer application. It shows all pdf files through a list and if I click one, the content of the file is displayed.

The app works very well when I click the file on the list, but it shuts down with a message <`Application has stopped`> when I launch the app in "Complete action using" screen.

I guess `setOnItemClickListener()` is not working on the app chooser. How to I fix this?

**MainActivity.java**

```
ListView lv_pdf;
public static ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
PDFAdapter obj_adapter;
public static int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS = 1;
boolean boolean_permission;
File dir;

private void init() {
    lv_pdf = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_pdf);
    dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    fn_permission();

    lv_pdf.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PdfActivity.class);
//PdfActivity.java file shows the content of a pdf file.

            intent.putExtra("position", i);
            startActivity(intent);

            Log.e("Position", i + "");
        }
    });
}

private void fn_permission() {
    if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
        if ((ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))) {

        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }
    else {
        boolean_permission = true;

        getfile(dir);

        obj_adapter = new PDFAdapter(getApplicationContext(), fileList);
        lv_pdf.setAdapter(obj_adapter);
//PDFAdapter.java sends adapter to listview.
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".PdfActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: share your crash report with question

Comment: @RatilalChopda There isn't any crash issues while compiling in Android Studio..Only the message <`Application has stopped`> appeared when I click the file in app chooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not providing any adapter to your listview.

Secondly you have to implement your click listener in adapter class.

To solve that provide an appropriate adapter to your listview then in that adapter class implement clicklistener method.

Comment: I already providing an adapter to listview through `fn_permission()` method.(I added it to the article) Do I have to add clicklistener method to adapter file?

Comment: Yes buddy inside adapter create clicklistener